# Accordion in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, xml, accordion, nativescript

So I was working with accordion plugin for nativescript. This plugin works just fine if the template of the item is fixed. Unfortunately in the application that I am trying to make the template isn't fixed. In one expansion panels the children are a slider and a label but in another one the children are radio buttons and text boxes. I need help as to how do I go about making such an UI.
Thanks for your help in advance!!

PS : This is the link for accordion and the example is in demo folder: https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-accordion

Answer (score 2):

For those who are facing the same problem I found out the solution. Instead of using accordion you should use the visibility attribute and toggle it accordingly.